# Regex to include alphanumeric and _

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match alphanumeric characters and the underscore `_`. This is my regex: `"\w_*[^-$\s\]"` and my impression is that this regex means any alphanumeric character `\w`, an underscore `_`, and no `-`,`$`, or whitespace. Is this correct?

Comment: `\w` covers also the `_` symbol.

Comment: Yes, and you should not escape the `]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are read as patterns which actually match characters in a string, left to right, so your pattern actually matches an alphanumeric, THEN an underscore (0 or more), THEN at least one character that is not a hyphen, dollar, or whitespace.

Since you're trying to alternate on character types, just use a character class to show what characters you're allowing:

```
[\w_]
```

This checks that ANY part of the string matches it, so let's anchor it to the beginning and and of the string:

```
^[\w_]$
```

And now we see that the character class lacks a quantifier, so we are matching on exactly ONE character. We can fix that using `+` (if you want one or more characters, no empty strings) or `*` (if you want to allow empty strings). I'll use `+` here.

```
^[\w_]+$
```

As it turns out, the `\w` character class already includes the underscore, so we can remove the redundant underscore from the pattern:

```
^[\w]+$
```

And now we have only one character in the character class, so we no longer need the character class brackets at all:

```
^\w+$
```

And that's all you need, unless I'm missing something about your requirements.

Comment: This answer assumes that we want to validate the *entire string* with the regular expression. Use @hwnd's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26442555/129655) if you want to check that there exists at least one alphanumeric/underscore in the string.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you are semi-correct if the closing bracket was not escaped and you edited your regex a bit. Also the token `\w` matches underscore, so you do not need to repeat this character. Your regular expression says:

```
\w         # word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
_*         # '_' (0 or more times)
[^-$\s]    # any character except: '-', '$', whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
```

You could simply write your entire regex as follows to match word characters:

```
\w+        # word characters ( a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ ) (1 or more times)
```

If you want to match an entire string, be sure to anchor your expression.

```
^\w+$
```

Explanation:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
 \w+       #   word characters ( a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ ) (1 or more times)
$          # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```